# Imprimir Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, printf

estou tentando imprimir um iframe que tenho em uma página do meu site, mas a janela de impressão não está abrindo quando uso o seguinte código:

```js
function printFunction() {
 window.frames["printf"].focus();
 window.frames["printf"].print();
}
```

```html
<iframe id="printf" name="printf"></iframe>
```

E quando eu uso apenas o windows.print();....ele abre a janela de impressão, mas imprime a página toda, e não apenas o conteúdo do iframe!

```js
function printFunction() {
 window.print();
}
```

```html
<iframe id="printf" name="printf"></iframe >
```

OBS.: O botão imprimir, chamará a function printFunction() por onclick;

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?